# PHP: Best way to extract text within parenthesis?

Tags: php, parsing, string

What's the best/most efficient way to extract text set between parenthesis? Say I wanted to get the string "text" from the string "ignore everything except this (text)" in the most efficient manner possible.

So far, the best I've come up with is this:

```
$fullString = "ignore everything except this (text)";
$start = strpos('(', $fullString);
$end = strlen($fullString) - strpos(')', $fullString);

$shortString = substr($fullString, $start, $end);
```

Is there a better way to do this? I know in general using regex tends to be less efficient, but unless I can reduce the number of function calls, perhaps this would be the best approach? Thoughts?

Comment: You might find [`s($fullString)->between("(", ")")`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L412) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 171, accepted):

i'd just do a regex and get it over with. unless you are doing enough iterations that it becomes a huge performance issue, it's just easier to code (and understand when you look back on it)

```
$text = 'ignore everything except this (text)';
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text, $match);
print $match[1];
```

Comment: No, it isn't: . only matches a single character.

Comment: not necessarily, ? is a lazy match. without it, a string like 'ignore (everything) except this (text)', the match would end up being 'everthing) except this (text'

Comment: Good to know. Should avoid all those squared nots. E.g. /src="([^"]*)"/ now replaced with /src="(.*?)"/ :D

Comment: It's good that you can "understand when you look back on it". Failing that, you've got some Stack Overflow comments to clarify it.

Comment: the /src="([^"]*)"/ is more efficient than /src="(.*?)"/

Comment: ya square nots are, the reason is ? makes the engine backtrack a lot, which is very expensive. the square nots will match "forward" in that sense. i prefer the ? notation though, so if performance isn't an issue i get lazy :)

Comment: Lazy matching `*?` will not outperform greedy matching `*`.  This is why using a negated character class is better than `.`.  See Rob's and Wiktor's answers for better patterns.

Answer (score 18):

So, actually, the code you posted doesn't work: `substr()'s` parameters are $string, $start and **$length**, and `strpos()'s` parameters are `$haystack`, `$needle`. Slightly modified:

```
$str = "ignore everything except this (text)";
$start  = strpos($str, '(');
$end    = strpos($str, ')', $start + 1);
$length = $end - $start;
$result = substr($str, $start + 1, $length - 1);
```

Some subtleties: I used `$start + 1` in the offset parameter in order to help PHP out while doing the `strpos()` search on the second parenthesis; we increment `$start` one and reduce `$length` to exclude the parentheses from the match.

Also, there's no error checking in this code: you'll want to make sure `$start` and `$end` do not === false before performing the `substr`.

As for using `strpos/substr` versus regex; performance-wise, this code will beat a regular expression hands down. It's a little wordier though. I eat and breathe `strpos/substr`, so I don't mind this too much, but someone else may prefer the compactness of a regex.

Comment: Note that if you modify this code to use strrpos (starts from the back of the string) on the $end then it will correctly handle cases where there are parens within.. like (well this is (very) nice).

Answer (score 14):

Use a regular expression:

```
if( preg_match( '!\(([^\)]+)\)!', $text, $match ) )
    $text = $match[1];
```

Answer (score 8):

i think this is the fastest way to get the words between the first parenthesis in a string.

```
$string = 'ignore everything except this (text)';
$string = explode(')', (explode('(', $string)[1]))[0];
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 5):

The already posted regex solutions - `\((.*?)\)` and `\(([^\)]+)\)` - do not return the *innermost* strings between an open and close brackets. If a string is `Text (abc(xyz 123)` they [both](https://regex101.com/r/247sJ2/1) [return](https://regex101.com/r/247sJ2/2) a `(abc(xyz 123)` as a whole match, and not `(xyz 123)`.

The pattern that matches substrings (use with `preg_match` to fetch the first and `preg_match_all` to fetch all occurrences) in parentheses without other open and close parentheses in between is, if the match should include parentheses:

```
\([^()]*\)
```

Or, you want to get values without parentheses:

```
\(([^()]*)\)        // get Group 1 values after a successful call to preg_match_all, see code below
\(\K[^()]*(?=\))    // this and the one below get the values without parentheses as whole matches 
(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\)) // less efficient, not recommended
```

Replace `*` with `+` if there must be at least 1 char between `(` and `)`.

**Details**:

- `\(` - an opening round bracket (must be escaped to denote a literal parenthesis as it is used outside a character class)
- `[^()]*` - [zero or more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) characters other than `(` and `)` (note these `(` and `)` do not have to be escaped inside a character class as inside it, `(` and `)` cannot be used to specify a grouping and are treated as literal parentheses)
- `\)` - a closing round bracket (must be escaped to denote a literal parenthesis as it is used outside a character class).

The `\(\K` part in an alternative regex matches `(` and omits from the match value (with the `\K` match reset operator). `(?<=\()` is a positive lookbehind that requires a `(` to appear immediately to the left of the current location, but the `(` is not added to the match value since lookbehind (lookaround) patterns are not consuming. `(?=\()` is a positive lookahead that requires a `)` char to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

[PHP code](https://3v4l.org/mBlbR):

```
$fullString = 'ignore everything except this (text) and (that (text here))';
if (preg_match_all('~\(([^()]*)\)~', $fullString, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]); // Get whole match values
    print_r($matches[1]); // Get Group 1 values
}
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => (text)  [1] => (text here) )
Array ( [0] => text    [1] => text here   )
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample code to extract all the text between '[' and ']' and store it 2 separate arrays(ie text inside parentheses in one array and text outside parentheses in another array)

```
   function extract_text($string)
   {
    $text_outside=array();
    $text_inside=array();
    $t="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)
    {
        if($string[$i]=='[')
        {
            $text_outside[]=$t;
            $t="";
            $t1="";
            $i++;
            while($string[$i]!=']')
            {
                $t1.=$string[$i];
                $i++;
            }
            $text_inside[] = $t1;

        }
        else {
            if($string[$i]!=']')
            $t.=$string[$i];
            else {
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
    if($t!="")
    $text_outside[]=$t;

    var_dump($text_outside);
    echo "\n\n";
    var_dump($text_inside);
  }
```

Output:
extract_text("hello how are you?");
will produce:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "hello how are you?"
}

array(0) {
}
```

extract_text("hello [http://www.google.com/test.mp3] how are you?");
will produce

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "hello "
  [1]=>
  string(13) " how are you?"
}


array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "http://www.google.com/test.mp3"
}
```

Comment: +1 but how do the same for [* and *] ? Because [] only maybe used on html for example.

Answer (score 3):

This function may be useful.

```
    public static function getStringBetween($str,$from,$to, $withFromAndTo = false)
    {
       $sub = substr($str, strpos($str,$from)+strlen($from),strlen($str));
       if ($withFromAndTo)
         return $from . substr($sub,0, strrpos($sub,$to)) . $to;
       else
         return substr($sub,0, strrpos($sub,$to));
    }
    $inputString = "ignore everything except this (text)";
    $outputString = getStringBetween($inputString, '(', ')'));
    echo $outputString; 
    //output will be test

    $outputString = getStringBetween($inputString, '(', ')', true));
    echo $outputString; 
    //output will be (test)
```

strpos() => which is used to find the position of first occurance in a string.

strrpos() => which is used to find the position of first occurance in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getStringsBetween($str, $start='[', $end=']', $with_from_to=true){
$arr = [];
$last_pos = 0;
$last_pos = strpos($str, $start, $last_pos);
while ($last_pos !== false) {
    $t = strpos($str, $end, $last_pos);
    $arr[] = ($with_from_to ? $start : '').substr($str, $last_pos + 1, $t - $last_pos - 1).($with_from_to ? $end : '');
    $last_pos = strpos($str, $start, $last_pos+1);
}
return $arr; }
```

this is a little improvement to the previous answer that will return all patterns in array form:

getStringsBetween('[T]his[] is [test] string [pattern]') will return:

Answer (score 0):

```php
function getAllStrings($inString, $inStart, $inEnd, $inBetween = FALSE)
{
   $list      = array();
   $last_pos  = strpos($inString, $inStart, 0);

   $len_start = strlen($inStart);
   $len_end   = strlen($inEnd);

   while ($last_pos !== FALSE)
   {
      $end_pos  = strpos($inString, $inEnd, $last_pos + $len_start);
      $list[]   = ($inBetween ? $inStart : '').substr($inString, $last_pos + $len_start, $end_pos - ($last_pos + $len_start)).($inBetween ? $inEnd : '');
      $last_pos     = strpos($inString, $inStart, $end_pos + $len_end);
   }

   return $list;
}
```

This function:

- accepts same delimiters - ex. a single quote ('test').
- accepts long delimiters - ex. a combination  (!@#test!@#)

Answer (score 0):

```php
function getAllStrings($inString, $inStart, $inEnd, $inBetween = FALSE)
{
   $list      = array();
   $last_pos  = strpos($inString, $inStart, 0);

   $len_start = strlen($inStart);
   $len_end   = strlen($inEnd);

   while ($last_pos !== FALSE)
   {
      $end_pos  = strpos($inString, $inEnd, $last_pos + $len_start);
      $list[]   = ($inBetween ? $inStart : '').substr($inString, $last_pos + $len_start, $end_pos - ($last_pos + $len_start)).($inBetween ? $inEnd : '');
      $last_pos     = strpos($inString, $inStart, $end_pos + $len_end);
   }

   return $list;
}
```

This function:

- accepts same delimiters - ex. a single quote ('test').
- accepts long delimiters - ex. a combination (!@#test!@#)