# PHP: how to get only the words between a parenthesis () and clear everything else

Tags: php

I have an array with some info. For example:

> (writer) &

or

> with (additional dialogue)

I want to clean this so I only get the text between the parenthesis () and clear everything else

result:

> writer

or

> additional dialogue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Best way to extract text within parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$string = "this (is (a) test) with (two parenthesis) duh";
```

For a string like this you can use preg_match_all and use implode.

```
$string = "this (is (a) test) with (two parenthesis) duh";
$regex = '#\((([^()]+|(?R))*)\)#';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $string ,$matches)) {
    echo implode(' ', $matches[1]);
} else {
    //no parenthesis
    echo $string;
}
```

Or you can use preg_replace, but with multiple parenthesis you'll lose the whitespace between them.

```
$regex = '#[^()]*\((([^()]+|(?R))*)\)[^()]*#';
$replacement = '\1';
echo preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $string);
```

I got a lot of help from this page, [Finer points of PHP regular expressions](http://www.skdevelopment.com/php-regular-expressions.php).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that PHP supported recursive regular expressions.

Comment: Also assertions, backreferences and conditions. You can read it here: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php#regexp.reference.back-references

Comment: The url in this answer is now dead but from that snippet, you can tell there is much to learn from it. So I searched for [a saved version](http://web.archive.org/web/20120403035903/http://www.skdevelopment.com/php-regular-expressions.php) from the wayback machine just in case anyone interested in seeing what other goodies are there

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way will be with a regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('/\((.*?)\)/', $input, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]`, etc will contain everything that was between parentheses in $input. That is, `$matches[1]` will have whatever was between the first set of parentheses, and so on (to handle cases with multiple sets).

Comment: "The easiest way will be with a regular expression:" ...not if you want the parenthesis to balance! How do you think the OP wants to process "this (is (a) test)"? Your regex matches that as "is (a". Also, it's faster (I think) to do /[^)]*\)/ than to do /.*?/ to get text between parenthesis.

Comment: If he had specified that there could be nested parentheses I wouldn't have suggested regex. But he seems to be dealing with pretty simple input overall. Writing a parser when a one-line regex will do the same job is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

```
$matches = array();
$num_matched = preg_match_all('/\((.*)\)/U', $input, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

> for examle you want the array of strings(keys) between {} in following
>   example, where '/' doesn't fall in-between

```
$str = "C://{ad_custom_attr1}/{upn}/{samaccountname}";
$str_arr = getInbetweenStrings('{', '}', $str);

print_r($str_arr);
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is the same as `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

Using above in a replace

```
echo preg_replace('/\(([\w]{1,2})\)/',"(s\\1)",'(Gs) Main Hall');
```

results in

```
(sGs) Main Hall
```