# Parse a string to extract function name and parameter for use with `call_user_func()`

Tags: php

How do I execute the `transaction(123)` function?

The response via API is: `transaction(123)`

I store this in the `$response` varible.

```
<?php

function transaction($orderid) {
  return  $orderid;
}

//api response
$response = "transaction(123)";

try {
  $orderid = call_user_func($response);
  echo  $orderid;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [manual page `call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) should be called with two parameters in your use case.

```
$orderid = call_user_func('transaction', 123);
```

This means you must extract the function and parameter separately from your `$response` variable:

```
preg_match('/([\w\_\d]+)\(([\w\W]*)\)/', $response, $matches);
```

Would result in the `$matches` array containing the function name at index 1 and the parameter at index 2.

So you would then do:

```
$orderid = call_user_func($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Obviously you need to be very careful with the values if they are coming from an untrusted source.

Comment: OK. So why the down vote? This is a perfectly legitimate answer.

Comment: How do I extract it.. example please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis

Comment: $matches[1] and $matches[2] return as array.

Comment: @user622378 updated. I didn't mean to use `preg_match_all()`, but `preg_match()` instead.

Comment: What if the API returns `do_something('evil')`?

Comment: @Denis Please see my caveat: "_Obviously you need to be very careful with the values if they are coming from an untrusted source._" in the answer I gave above. I have left the filtering up to the question proposer.

Answer (score 3):

The bad way to do it, is to use the `eval()` function. It's **very** bad in your use-case because the API may very well return things you don't want to execute.

The good way to do it is to parse your string, validate its contents, and map the call and its arguments accordingly.

You can parse the return string using a regular expression:

```
preg_match("/^(.+?)\((.*?)\)$/", $answer, $match);
var_dump($match[1]); // method
var_dump(explode(',', $match[2])); // arguments
```

You **must** sanitize/validate the above.

Answer (score 1):

Call call_user_func this way:

```
$orderid = call_user_func('transaction', 123);
```

Additionally, take a look at http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: I know about this but I need to get a value of 123 or argument to do this.

Comment: @user622378: Looking at your code, it seems like you actually didn't know about this.