# PHP/REGEX: Get a string within parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

This is a really simple problem, but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

I'm try to use preg_match or preg_match_all to obtain a string from within parentheses, **but without the parentheses**.

So far, my expression looks like this:

```
\([A-Za-z0-9 ]+\)
```

and returns the following result:

> 3(hollow highlight) 928-129 (<- original string)
>
> (hollow highlight) (<- result)

What i want is the string within parentheses, but without the parentheses. It would look like this:

> hollow highlight

I could probably replace the parentheses afterwards with str_replace or something, but that doesn't seem to be a very elegant solution to me.

What do I have to add, so the parentheses aren't included in the result?

Thanks for your help, you guys are great! :)

Comment: What you're calling brackets are actually parentheses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Best way to extract text within parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to add capturing parenthesis, in addition to your escaped parenthesis.

```
<?php
    $in = "hello (world), my name (is andrew) and my number is (845) 235-0184";
    preg_match_all('/\(([A-Za-z0-9 ]+?)\)/', $in, $out);
    print_r($out[1]);
?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => world [1] => is andrew [2] => 845 )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works great (besides the escaped backslashes). But how do brackets help? I thought my expression was read like this: "an open bracket followed by amount of chars that consist of letters, numbers and spaces, followed by a closed bracket". How do the (non-escaped-)brackets come into play here? Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Oops, sorry about the escaped backslashes; fixed now.  Non-escaped brackets have a special meaning: capture.  See, by default, the entire match is captured into ``[0]``, which is why ``$out[0]`` contains everything, even the brackets you don't want.  Each ``()`` capture, well, _captures_ whatever's in between them, and stores them in sequential array indices, i.e. ``[1]``, ``[2]``, ``[3]``, etc.  For example, if your string is "abc123def456" and your regex is ``/abc(\d+)(\w+)(\d)(\d+)/``, your captures would be like so: ``[1]`` = "123", ``[2]`` = "def", ``[3]`` = "4", and ``[4]`` = "56".

Comment: The difference between ``preg_match`` and ``preg_match_all`` is that the latter will, as the name suggests, match all, so that there will be an array within the array: ``[1] = { "world", "is andrew", "845" }``.

Comment: Thank you acheong87. I tried reading it up myself, but I didn't get it. Your explanation however was great, I understand now. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 26):

try:

```
preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/', $s, $a);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (hollow highlight)
    [1] => hollow highlight
)
```