# Extract time within parentheses using PHP

Tags: php, regex, trim

This is my first time using the trim function and I want to get the Time excluding the open and close parenthesis of my string. Can you give me hints and suggestions on how to do this?

```
$string = "Updated by Carewina Almonte  (04/02/2018 21:58:32)";     
echo trim($string, "Updated by Carewina Almonte  (04/02/2018");     
exit();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249445/php-regex-get-a-string-within-parentheses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP/REGEX: Get a string within parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249445/php-regex-get-a-string-within-parentheses)

Comment: if the format is constant, you could just use substr() other wise a regular expression, trim() is not really sutiable here

Answer (score 3):

In php, You can do get this and this works if and only if date and time always appears at the end of string -

```
 $string = "Updated by Carewina Almonte  (04/02/2018 21:58:32)";
 $time = substr($string,-9,8);
 echo $time;
```

Comment: I don't get it, why is this answer getting upvoted. OP has not mentioned that the string is of specific pattern. I think using regular expression is the only choice since we don't know anything except that the string is inside parentheses.

Comment: @roundAbout I posted this because there is a chance of a string pattern. If there exists pattern then this answer could be the simplest and effective one. I might be wrong because I always thinks that if something is going to be done with simple things then why to go to harder. Anyway thanks. You can downvote as you did. Someone might think it's better to go with simple solutions .... I think simple code also deserve upvote to...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this task:

```
$str = 'Updated by Carewina Almonte  (04/02/2018 21:58:32)';
preg_match('/(?<=\(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} ).*(?=\))/', $str, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

**Breakdown:**

- Positive Lookbehind `(?<=\()`. Assert that the Regex below matches:

  - `\(` matches the character `(` literally (case sensitive)
  - `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\d{2}` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
  - `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly `2` times
  - `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
- Positive Lookahead `(?=\))`. Assert that the Regex below matches:

  - `\)` matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: he wants the time not the date.

Comment: @Wils I realized it after your comment. I have already updated the answer.

Comment: One of the beautiful things `PHP` offers is the possibility to use other delimiters, so that you don't have to escape everything. That being said, you could rewrite your expression to `~(?<=\(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} ).*(?=\))~`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Updated by Carewina Almonte  (04/02/2018 21:58:32)";     

if(preg_match("/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/", $string , $match))
{

    echo $match[0];
}
```

Regular expression should be used in this case.

Comment: This regex will match any `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}`. OP is specifically looking for time within parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

For you example string you might match what is between parenthesis using [`\(\K[^)]+(?=\))`](https://regex101.com/r/xKj3F3/1/).

This will match an opening parenthesis `\(` and then use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

After that match NOT a closing parenthesis one or more times `[^)]+` and a positive lookahead to assert that what follows is a closing parenthesis `(?=\))`.

Then you could create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) using or use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) using `$matches[0]`  and extract the time:

```
$re = '/\(\K[^)]+(?=\))/';
$str = 'Updated by Carewina Almonte  (04/02/2018 21:58:32)';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$dateTime = new DateTime($matches[0]);
if ($dateTime !== false) {
    echo $dateTime->format('H:i:s');
}
```

[Test](https://3v4l.org/Blv3t)