# Extract text from a string that contains brackets in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string with State name and code like this

```
KT16(Ottershaw)
```

Now i need to extract text from `()`. I need to extract Ottershaw. How can i do this with php.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

should be :

```
preg_match('/\(([^\)]*)\)/', 'KT16(Ottershaw)', $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Regex is great i like the way

Answer (score 6):

Just get the substring between the first opening bracket and the last closing bracket:

```
$string = "KT16(Ottershaw)";
$strResult = substr($string, stripos($string, "(") +1,strrpos($string, ")") - stripos($string, "(")-1);
```

Comment: Yeah, not all the problems need a regex

Comment: No. It is also working with `$string = "KT16(Otte (rshaw))";`

Comment: What about `$string = "KT16(Otte) test (rshaw)";` ? I'll still give you +1 thought :p

Comment: Now i understand what you mean... Yes you are right, but it wasn't in the question. I thought it would be nice to get it even there are further brackets in the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code to extract all the text between '[' and ']' and store it 2 separate arrays(ie text inside parentheses in one array and text outside parentheses in another array)

```
function extract_text($string)
   {
    $text_outside=array();
    $text_inside=array();
    $t="";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++)
    {
        if($string[$i]=='[')
        {
            $text_outside[]=$t;
            $t="";
            $t1="";
            $i++;
            while($string[$i]!=']')
            {
                $t1.=$string[$i];
                $i++;
            }
            $text_inside[] = $t1;

        }
        else {
            if($string[$i]!=']')
            $t.=$string[$i];
            else {
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
    if($t!="")
    $text_outside[]=$t;

    var_dump($text_outside);
    echo "\n\n";
    var_dump($text_inside);
  }
```

Output: extract_text("hello how are you?"); will produce:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "hello how are you?"
}

array(0) {
}
```

extract_text("hello [http://www.google.com/test.mp3] how are you?"); will produce

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "hello "
  [1]=>
  string(13) " how are you?"
}


array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "http://www.google.com/test.mp3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following RegEx should work:

```
/\[(.*?)\]/
```