# PHP split string into 2 variables from containing brackets

Tags: php

I am using a regular expression [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196645/560287) although this only extracts the text inside of the brackets, I want to completely remove it:

```
if( preg_match( '!\(([^\)]+)\)!', $text, $match ) )
    $text = $match[1];
```

E.g I have: `my long text string (with another string)`

How can I get:

```
$var1 = "my long text string";
$var2 = "with another string";
```

Comment: What should happen if there's something after the closing parentheses?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// This is all you need
<?php $data = explode('(' , rtrim($str, ')')); ?>
```

Example:

```
<?php
$str = 'your long text string (with another string)';
$data = explode('(' , rtrim($str, ')'));    

print_r($data);


// output 

// Array
// (
//     [0] => my long text string 
//     [1] => with another string
// )
// profit $$$$

?>
```

Comment: Good solution. However, take note that you need to convert the end result from array to a string if that is what you want like OP.

Answer (score 5):

```
$data = preg_split("/[()]+/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I believe you'd have to escape the `(` and `)`'s, though.

Comment: not inside the [ ] because inside [ ], all special characters are normal :p. Take a look at : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2249ca5e439760eec25161a6b14b2cdbfd18ecc3

Answer (score 1):

You could use the code below. But keep in mind that you do need some extra checking to see if there really is an `$out[0][0]` and `$out[0][1]`

```
    <?php
    $string = "my long text string (with another string)";
    preg_match_all("/(.*)\((.*)\)/", $string, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    print_r($out);
    /*
    Array
    (
            [0] => Array
                    (
                            [0] => my long text string (with another string)
                            [1] => my long text string 
                            [2] => with another string
                    )

    )
    */

    $var1 = $out[0][1];
    $var2 = $out[0][2];
    //$var1 = "my long text string";
    //$var2 = "with another string";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not so good in regular expression, but you can try this.....

```
$exp=explode("(", $text);
$text1=$exp[0];
$text2=str_replace(array("(",")"), array('',''), $exp[1]);
```

Comment: Nice idea thanks, although I think I would prefer to use the `trim` instead of `str_replace`

Answer (score 1):

```
'([^\)]+)\(([^\)]+)\)'
```

Just remove the !-chars and add a another variable field (the name for brackets-area?) and its ready :)

http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php is worth knowing to get some testing quickly done!

Answer (score 1):

this is a very detailed code... you can do it shorter...

```
<?php
$longtext = "my long text string (with another string)";
$firstParantheses = strpos($longtext,"(");

$firstText = substr($longtext,0,$firstParantheses);

$secondText = substr($longtext,$firstParantheses);

$secondTextWithoutParantheses = str_replace("(","",$secondText);
$secondTextWithoutParantheses = str_replace(")","",$secondTextWithoutParantheses);

$finalFirstPart = $firstText;
$finalSecondPart = $secondTextWithoutParantheses;

echo $finalFirstPart." ------- ".$finalSecondPart;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this workaround:

```
$vars = explode('@@', str_replace(array('(', ')'), '@@', $text));
```

It will replace the brackets with @@ and then explode the text to an array. Additionally you can use array_filter to remove possible empty positions.