# Finding and replacing Stack Overflow style links within a string

Tags: php, html, regex, string

I have a user input string with Stack Overflow style links within the string like this:

`The input string [foo](http://foo.com) with a link.`

and I need to transform the string to include anchor tags like this:

`The input string <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a> with a link.`

So far, I've got (referenced from: [PHP: Best way to extract text within parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis)):

```
$text = 'ignore everything except this (text)';
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $text, $match);
print $match[1];
```

But I need to find a way to match both the element within parentheses and the element within brackets. And finally, replace the entire matched section with a the correctly formatted anchor tag.

Does anyone know the correct regex syntax to match `[foo](http://foo.com)` and further how to extract "foo" and "http://foo.com"?

Comment: Look for an existing MarkDown parser. They're usually using regex for this very case too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on the markdown parser. There seems to be a really good one here: http://parsedown.org/ for my purposes it might be a bit too powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would match the string which is in `[blah](http://blah.blah)` format. The characters inside the first `[]` braces are captured into the group 1 and the charcters inside the next `()` braces are captured into group 2. Later the charcetrs inside group 1 and 2 are referenced through back-referencing (ie, recalling it with  `\1` or `\2`)

**Regex:**

```
\[([^]]*)\]\(([^)]*)\)
```

**Replacement string:**

```
<a href="\2">\1</a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rZ8bG0/2)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = "The input string [foo](http://foo.com) with a link";
echo preg_replace('~\[([^]]*)\]\(([^)]*)\)~', '<a href="\2">\1</a>', $mystring);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
The input string <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a> with a link
```

Comment: Look, that's a well-written regex, as always. But just providing code-dump answers is not very helpful. In particular when OP struggles with the syntax a little explanation would be appropriate. The DEMO link does not substitute that.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been trying to create. Thank you so much for this. I'll be accepting this answer in a minute.