# PHP - Need help extracting multiple strings with regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am having trouble extracting some patterns from a string using PHP.  Here is the example string:

```
"New [[supplier]] price request for [[legal-entity]]"
```

What I need to do is extract all the "merge tags" (in brackets), from that string and output in an array.  The array I need is:

```
array(
    0 => "[[supplier]]',
    1 => "[[legal-entity]]"
);
```

Comment: Have a look at [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). Search SO for previous answers too - this is definitely a question that I've seen before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Best way to extract text within parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the expression:

```
\[\[[^]]+\]\]
```

- `\[\[` Two `[` brackets.
- `[^]]+` Negated character set, anything that is not a `]`.
- `\]\]` Two `]` brackets.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/X7dF4Z/1).

---

In PHP:

```
<?php

$input = 'New [[supplier]] price request for [[legal-entity]]';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\[\[[^]]+\]\]/s', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Prints:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [[supplier]]
            [1] => [[legal-entity]]
        )
```

PHP demo [here](https://ideone.com/sIBf0v).

Comment: I like that character negation, nice one

Comment: You are welcome. Cheers @DarraghEnright, yes the negated character set requires less steps than matching anything lazily, compare the two debuggers: [negated character set](https://regex101.com/r/X7dF4Z/1/debugger) vs [anything lazily](https://regex101.com/r/X7dF4Z/2/debugger)