# How to put specific string in into array?

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

> [Rise] and rise [again] until lambs become [lions].

I want to get all the string inside the [] (Rise, again, lions) and put it in to an array. How can I do this?

Edit: Thank you guys, I already found the solution here: [PHP: Best way to extract text within parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196520/php-best-way-to-extract-text-within-parenthesis)

Comment: can you show the array struture where you have those keys ?

Comment: Close the question by deleting it or post your edit as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Matt I think it's easier to just flag the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Matthew True, forgot about that haha

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with **regular expressions**:

```
$s = '[Rise] and rise [again] until lambs become [lions].';

preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', $s, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```